# Does running pygame usually make computers warm

Tags: python, pygame

When I run a simple pygame program using PyCharm on my M1 MacBook, I notice that my laptop gets kinda warm after running the program for 5-10 minutes. Is this normal, or does the while loop "tax" the computer. Thanks.

Code below:

```
import pygame
# INITIALIZE
pygame.init
#CREATE THE SCREEN
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#Title and Icon

pygame.display.set_caption("First Pygame")

#Player

playerImg = pygame.image.load("racing-car.png")
playerX= 400
playerY=300
playerX_Change=0
playerY_Change=0

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX,playerY))

# Game Loop
running=True
while running:
    screen.fill((128, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_Change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_Change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_Change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_Change = -5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            playerX_Change=0
            playerY_Change=0
    playerY=playerY+playerY_Change
    playerX=playerX+playerX_Change
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This is way off-topic for this site but you can profile your code and see what's taking up the most time and resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script

Comment: Any energy transfer moves atoms, which generates heat, so yes

Comment: You are running the CPU full bore if you have no wait statements.  IIRC there is a `pygame.time.wait(1)` or some such call you can have in your loop.  Watch CPU usage monitor with and without that statement.

Comment: `pygame.event.wait()` might be a good alternative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the following loop only runs 60 times per second.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]
```